# Lstm regression options matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, regression, lstm, prediction

Why are the time series predictions using LSTM regression are different for different runs while the same hyperparameter values are used at the different runs?

Comment: try fixing the [seed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html)?

Comment: @Ather Cheema, Dear thanks for your reply, Can you enlighten how to do that,

Comment: I have use the following LSTM architecture and training options     layers=[...
        sequenceInputLayer(numFeatures)
        lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits)
        dropoutLayer(0.3)
        fullyConnectedLayer(numResponses)
             regressionLayer];
  options=trainingOptions('adam',....
      'MaxEpochs',maxEpoch,...
      'GradientThreshold',1,....
      'InitialLearnRate',0.05,...
      'LearnRateSchedule','piecewise',...
      'LearnRateDropPeriod',LRD,...
      'LearnRateDropFactor',LRDF,...
      'Verbose',0,...
      'Shuffle','never',...
      'Plots','none');